# How to retrieve the android sdk version?

Tags: android, sdk, version

How can I get the current `Android SDK` version(1.5, 1.6, 2.0, etc.) programmatically?

Comment: Please edit the title of your question. Like "Retrieve android sdk version"

Comment: I'd like the answer to this as well. I'm not at the point where I can run tests so I can't print any constants out. I downloaded it about a month ago and can't find the version number.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The String [`Build.VERSION.RELEASE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#RELEASE) will give you the user-visible version string (i.e 1.5, 1.6, 2.0), while [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) will give you a value from [`Build.VERSION_CODES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES) that would be better to use if you want to compare against it programatically.

Comment: Note that Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is only available on Android 1.6 and newer. Build.VERSION.SDK will work on all Android releases, including 1.5. However, once you elect to drop 1.5 support, switching to SDK_INT is a good idea.

Comment: String readAbleAndroidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

Comment: The ActionBar compat lib uses the Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH constant and it doesn't crash on the 1.6 emulator. How can this happen?

Answer (score 25):

```
  StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    buf.append("VERSION.RELEASE {"+Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"}");
    buf.append("\\nVERSION.INCREMENTAL {"+Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL+"}");
    buf.append("\\nVERSION.SDK {"+Build.VERSION.SDK+"}");
    buf.append("\\nBOARD {"+Build.BOARD+"}");
    buf.append("\\nBRAND {"+Build.BRAND+"}");
    buf.append("\\nDEVICE {"+Build.DEVICE+"}");
    buf.append("\\nFINGERPRINT {"+Build.FINGERPRINT+"}");
    buf.append("\\nHOST {"+Build.HOST+"}");
    buf.append("\\nID {"+Build.ID+"}");

    Log.d("build",buf.toString());
```