# Retrieving Android API version programmatically

Tags: android, android-api-levels

Is there any way to get the API version that the phone is currently running?

Answer (score 1200):

As described in the Android documentation, the SDK level (integer) the phone is running is available in:

[`android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT)

The class corresponding to this int is in the [`android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) class.

Code example:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Do something for lollipop and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
}
```

**Edit**: This SDK_INT is available since Donut (android 1.6 / API4) so make sure your application is not retro-compatible with Cupcake (android 1.5 / API3) when you use it or your application will crash (thanks to Programmer Bruce for the precision).

Corresponding android documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

Comment: If the code is running on 1.5, then referencing SDK_INT will throw an exception, since it was introduced with API 4.  (Yes, you can run an APK compiled with API 4 code on 1.5.  And yes, when that API 4 code is reached, it does throw an exception.)

Comment: @ProgrammerBruce how to prevent the crash? Or how to _not_ be retro-compatible?

Comment: @Cœur I think building an app retro compatible to Android 1.5 is not really useful nowadays. Just set your project `minSdkVersion` to `4` (Android 1.6) and go on.

Comment: Why not use the String **android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK** instead? It works for all Android versions

Comment: @PYK This attribute android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK is deprecated, so it should not be used. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK

Answer (score 195):

## Very easy:

```
   String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
   String model = Build.MODEL;
   int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
   String versionRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

Log.e("MyActivity", "manufacturer " + manufacturer
            + " \n model " + model
            + " \n version " + version
            + " \n versionRelease " + versionRelease
    );
```

#### Output:

```
E/MyActivity:   manufacturer ManufacturerX
                model SM-T310 
                version 19 
                versionRelease 4.4.2
```

Comment: Build.VERSION.RELEASE is what I was looking for. Thanks @CommonSenseCode

Comment: Just remembering that SDK_INT was added in API level 4

Answer (score 93):

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

That will give you the actual numbers of your version; aka 2.3.3 or 2.2.
The problem with using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is if you have a rooted phone or custom rom, you could have a non standard OS (aka my android is running 2.3.5) and that will return a null when using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT so Build.VERSION.RELEASE will work no matter using standard Android version or not !

To use it, you could just do this;

```
String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Comment: According to docs `int android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and 
`public static final int SDK_INT` and 
`Added in API level 4` how could int (not Integer) return `NULL`? `NULL` is a state for an object so its Build or VERSION could be `null` theoretically but in such case not only `SDK_INT` but `RELEASE` as well will cause a NPE. SDK_INT could probably cause "No such method exception" or something like that but not null or NPE. If only custom ROM breaks the docs and the method declared as `public static final Integer SDK_INT`. I'm just trying to determine an issue's nature to make a workaround.

Comment: Can anyone verify if this is in fact the case? Stan's comment makes it pretty clear that null is not possible. And custom Android ROM's / OS's surely have to originate from some build of version? So surely Build.VERSION.SDK_INT should reflect this?

Comment: I've downvoted this since the claim isn't really backed up and the warning about `null` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Rooted phone or Custom roms should never touch this number. They usually change the Build.VERSION.RELEASE though.

Comment: There is a lot of known issues when it comes to Custom OS/Roms.  The version I had on my older Android at the time (I want to say GS3) had that issue.  There has been a lot of issues with hardcoded values or values there weren't just correct.  Hard example, Wi-Fi Mac Addresses being hard coded.

Comment: If custom ROM developers is purposely changing the Android API signatures, then they're purposely sabotaging those.

Answer (score 39):

try this:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
 }
```

Answer (score 32):

Taking into account all said, here is the code I use for detecting if device has Froyo or newer Android OS (2.2+):

```
public static boolean froyoOrNewer() {
    // SDK_INT is introduced in 1.6 (API Level 4) so code referencing that would fail
    // Also we can't use SDK_INT since some modified ROMs play around with this value, RELEASE is most versatile variable
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("1.") ||
        android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("2.0") ||
        android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("2.1"))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Obviously, you can modify that if condition to take into account 1.0 & 1.5 versions of Android in case you need generic checker. You will probably end up with something like this:

```
// returns true if current Android OS on device is >= verCode 
public static boolean androidMinimum(int verCode) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("1.0"))
        return verCode == 1;
    else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("1.1")) {
        return verCode <= 2;
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("1.5")) {
        return verCode <= 3;
    } else {
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= verCode;
    }
}
```

Let me know if code is not working for you.

Answer (score 9):

android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK should give you the value of the API Level. You can easily find the mapping from api level to android version in the android documentation. I believe, 8 is for 2.2, 7 for 2.1, and so on.

Comment: This method is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

SDK.INT is supported for **Android 1.6** and up

SDK is supported for **all versions**

So I do:

```
String sdk_version_number = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
```

Credits to: [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) over this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882883/how-to-retrieve-the-android-sdk-version)

Comment: SDK deprecated in Java.

Comment: @limonik You're right, SDK exists since API level 1 but it was deprecated in API level 15

Answer (score 3):

Got it. Its using the `getApplicationInfo()` method of the `Context` class.

Comment: This will get you the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion of the APK, which describes which API versions the app supports. This is not the API version of the phone the app is currently running on.

Answer (score 2):

I generally prefer to add these codes in a function to get the Android version:

```
int whichAndroidVersion;

whichAndroidVersion= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
textView.setText("" + whichAndroidVersion); //If you don't use "" then app crashes.
```

For example, that code above will set the text into my textView as "29" now.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer have the version as number to be handeled more easyway than i wrote this:

```
  public static float getAPIVerison() {

    Float f = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
        strBuild.append(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.substring(0, 2));
        f = new Float(strBuild.toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.e("", "error retriving api version" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return f.floatValue();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I improved code i used

```
public static float getAPIVerison() {

    float f=1f;
    try {
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
        strBuild.append(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.substring(0, 2));
        f= Float.valueOf(strBuild.toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.e("myApp", "error retriving api version" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return f;
}
```