# Android API Version programmatically

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving Android API version programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)

I am trying to retrieve the current API Version of the device my Application is Running. Is there a way i can get that and Store it on a String. This needs to Work on 1.5 Version and Up. Examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: its actually very easy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35073538/4031815

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can get it by calling `Build.VERSION.SDK`.

From 1.6 on, you should use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` instead
because `Build.VERSION.SDK` is deprecated.

Comment: Awesome Thanks A Bunch for the quick response

Comment: Deprecated - yes. But how should I determine I got Cupcake or lower? Accessing SDK_INT fails on devices prior to Donut, as it was defined in API Level 4!

Comment: Check out my answer on other question for code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically/11683754#11683754

Comment: The enum corresponding to this int is in the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES class.


int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}

Edit: This SDK_INT is available since Donut (android 1.6 / API4) so make sure your application is not retro-compatible with Cupcake (android 1.5 / API3) when you use it or your application will crash (thanks to Programmer Bruce for the precision).

Answer (score 22):

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

That will give you the actual numbers of your version; aka 2.3.3 or 2.2.

The problem with using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is if you have a rooted phone or custom rom, you could have a none standard OS (aka my android is running 2.3.5) and that will return a `NULL` when using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT so Build.VERSION.RELEASE will work no matter what!

Comment: wouldn't SDK_INT return 0 not null?

Answer (score 20):

It is defined on the [`android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) constant, just use it.

Comment: +1 for drawing faster :)

Comment: Awesome Thanks A Bunch for the quick response