# how to compare Android versions

Tags: android, version, android-version

I am trying to create a condition in my code to compare Android versions.Something akin to;

```
if(version < 2.2)
{// TODO } 
else
{// TODO }
```

Would anyone please let me know how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506792/android-api-version-programmatically

Comment: Refer this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically

Comment: I found great thread about comparison, read it, best of all: http://www.osbuzzer.com/f5/difference-between-android-2-2-froyo-android-2-3-gingerbread-158/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare them as their integer version using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`, so for SDK v 2.2 you will get integer with value `8`, while SDK v 3.0 you will get `11`.

And please look at this [bunch of how to get android version question asked and answered again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526615/to-get-android-os-version-at-run-time), I suggest you to use the search box, and glance to the related question provided while you are writing your question :)

Comment: Ayublin, you are a life saver. Thanks a great deal!!

Answer (score 5):

Use This code:

```
int currentVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Do something for lollipop and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ttry this:

```
private boolean compareVersion(String currrentsVersion, String officialVersion) {
    isEqual = false;

    String[] string1 = currrentsVersion.split("[.]");
    String[] string2 = officialVersion.split("[.]");
    Integer[] number2 = new Integer[string2.length];

    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[string2.length];


    for (int i = 0; i < string2.length; i++) {
        if (string1.length-1<i)
            numbers[i] = 0;
        else
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(string1[i]);
        System.out.println("number1 ::: " + numbers[i]);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < string2.length; i++) {
        number2[i] = Integer.parseInt(string2[i]);
        System.out.println("number2 ::: " + number2[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number2.length; i++) {
        if (number2[i] > numbers[i]) {
            isEqual = false;
            break;
        } else {
            isEqual = true;
        }
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

Call this method where you want to compare the version.

```
if (compareVersion(getVersionInfo(), officialVersion)) 
    tvUpdateStatus.setText("Have the latest version installed :) ");
else 
    tvUpdateStatus.setText("Plz Update the Application");
```

I hope it'll help. ;)

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.