# How can we check Programmatically the version of Android OS?

Tags: android

How to check the Android Os version Programmatically on the onCreate of very first screen of the App?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving Android API version programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Android API version programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some hints to get you going bro :)

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
buf.append("VERSION.RELEASE {"+Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"}");
buf.append("\nVERSION.INCREMENTAL {"+Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL+"}");
buf.append("\nVERSION.SDK {"+Build.VERSION.SDK+"}");
buf.append("\nBOARD {"+Build.BOARD+"}");
buf.append("\nBRAND {"+Build.BRAND+"}");
buf.append("\nDEVICE {"+Build.DEVICE+"}");
buf.append("\nFINGERPRINT {"+Build.FINGERPRINT+"}");
buf.append("\nHOST {"+Build.HOST+"}");
buf.append("\nID {"+Build.ID+"}");
Log.d("build",buf);
```

Comment: The value you should be most interested in is `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` - `Build.VERSION.SDK` is the deprecated string form of the same data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

That will give you the actual numbers of your version; aka 2.3.3 or 2.2.
The problem with using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is if you have a rooted phone or custom rom, you could have a none standard OS (aka my android is running 2.3.5) and that will return a null when using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT so Build.VERSION.RELEASE will work no matter what!

To use it, you could just do this;

```
String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```