# Using android version programmatically

Tags: android, animation

I need to implements animations in my android application.But All version of android os does not support that animation . 
Now I want to make that if target device’s os support animation then some animation’s code should be executed other wise not ..

For this, I have coded as follow ,

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 7){overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in,R.anim.slide_left_out);}
```

But it will crach when activity start as it raise error while build time.

Plz give me solution if possible

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html) on Android developer website. And take a look at Google I/O 2011, it has a good session on this, look at 6 minute mark of [Android Protips: Advanced Topics for Expert Android App Developers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8) session.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}
```

Comment: This won't work, since the bit of code for Froyo won't work on pre-Froyo devices. In particular, if it references Froyo-only classes, you'll raise a ClassNotFoundException as soon as this class is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically/3940823) previous post.