# Replacement for `__system_property_get` in Android L NDK

Tags: android-ndk-r5

As of the Android L NDK, `__system_property_get` is removed (https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-reviews/keQP6L9aVyU). Is there another API in the Android L NDK to access the same property values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went with `popen` as detailed in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/478960/2833126 to run `getprop`. Something like

```
std::string command = "getprop ro.product.model";
FILE* file = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
if (!file) {
    // error
}
// read the property value from file
pclose(file);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `__system_property_read` / `__system_property_read_callback` (`__ANDROID_API__ >= 26`). I couldn't find official doc about it but it's well documented in `system_properties.h`.

I know it's not for `Android L` but I think a more modern solution should be written.

```
#include <sys/system_properties.h>

const prop_info* pi = __system_property_find("persist.sys.locale");
std::string prop;  // Not local, it will be modified by the callback.
if (pi != nullptr) {
  __system_property_read_callback(
      pi,
      [](void* cookie, const char*, const char* value, unsigned int) {
        *prop = value;
      },
       &prop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
androidVersion = system("getprop ro.build.version.release");

   printf("%s", androidVersion.c_str());
```