# Android custom alertdialog different on ICS and Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom alertdialog that inflates this custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/infoLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infoVersionTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center"
            android:text="@string/infoVersion"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infoVersionTitleValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoDetailText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have this in my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
........
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
```

And I've got style.xml defined this way:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>
</resources>
```

style.xml v11 defined like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>
</resources>
```

And style.xml v14 defined like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
</resources>
```

When running this on a 4.0.3 device it shows like this:

[image]

And running on a 2.3.3 device it shows like this:

[image]

On 2.3.3 devices, text is almost unreadable and I want to show white background (title bar included)

Is it possible to make the custom alertdialog show on all devices like it shows on 4.0.3?

I've saw [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html) but cant't seem to figure it out.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for this purpose

Check the description in [Theming](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) page for Dialog

Comment: Thanks but was looking for something without using third party solutions. Will look into that to see. But what can I do to when on 2.3.3 devices, the custom alertdialog shows black but with white letters. This way text will be readable

Comment: If you don't want to use any third party solutions, then you can have a look at their source codes and get the idea how they have done it.

Here is samples and source codes for [Holo every where](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere)

Comment: Ok will look into that also. Isn't there a way to force, on gingerbread devices, the alertdialog show with default gingerbread theme?

Comment: I think with this [suggested approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically) you can get the API version dynamically and based on that set your favorite theme for dialog.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock doesn't have a dialog theme anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Try calling `AlertDialog.Builder#setInverseBackgroundForced(true)` when you create your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure compatibility for all devices:

```
setInverseBackgroundForced(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? false
                                    : true)
```

This makes sure devices below HoneyCromb display normally and devices below are inverted!

Here is an example:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? false
                        : true);
dialog.setMessage("Test Dialog!");
dialog.create().show();
```

See the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setInverseBackgroundForced(boolean)