# Checking Android version programmatically

Tags: android

I need to check the Android version of my phone and if the version is less than 4.0.0 i should execute the following code otherwise it should not execute. How could I do it?
I used this line to get the Android version.

```
String androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

How could I check whether less than 4.0.0. Suggest me a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073538/4031815

Answer (score 23):

Something like this :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

}
```

and for more version check out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)!

Answer (score 8):

You can get any detail about phone like this -> and android.os.Build help you to get this

```
 System.out.println("button press on device name = "+android.os.Build.MODEL +" brand = "+android.os.Build.BRAND +" OS version = "+android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE + " SDK version = " +android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
```

Answer (score 7):

use

```
 int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;


    if (currentapiVersion >= 14) {
        // Do something for 14 and above versions


    } else {

         // do something for phones running an SDK before 14

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
    // Do your code for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do your code for before froyo versions
}
```