# How can I determine my Android API level?

Tags: android

How can I know which Android API level I am using. I need to make sure I am using version 1.1.0.

Edit:

My bad. I need level 14.

Thank you.

Comment: 1.1? no devices even use that

Comment: 1.1.0 never existed has an API level, These are Android API level http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

`Build.VERSION.RELEASE` will give you the version number as a String, such as `1.5`

Comment: Where is Build.Version.Release located?

Comment: android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know which Android API level I am using

I do not know what you mean by "using".

You can determine the API Level of the device that you are running on via `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`.

> I need to make sure I am using version 1.1.0

There was never a "1.1.0" release of Android. Android 1.1 did not have a ".0" suffix. Android 1.1 was released in early 2009 and is used on approximately zero devices today.

Answer (score 0):

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

In general you're also interested in the `compileSdkVersion` of the project, which you can see in your build.gradle file.