# Get Android Version

Tags: android, android-studio

I want get my android version, I'am using android studio and Android 4.3 for SDk. 
I try :

```
String deviceAndroidVersion =Build.VERSION;
```

and get error message :

```
Error:(58, 40) error: cannot find symbol variable VERSION
```

I try to another way almost suggest that way to get android version.
Thankyou

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically

Comment: @Naytzyrhc thank you for direct to that link. it solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String deviceAndroidVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SDK version

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

Or this for the actual numbers...

```
Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```