# android sdk version to string

Tags: java, android, sdk

I have an activity that requires SDK but still want to make the rest of the app available for lower SDK versions. Is there a way of reading the users SDK to a string so I can place in an if statement please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically Apologies, just found this

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ... do stuff ...
    }
```