# ConnectivityManager Not working in android 6.0

Tags: android

The code i am using to check internet connectivity so far is

```
private boolean isOnline() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

my code is working fine till android 5.0 but in android 6.0 the app crashes can anyone help me regarding this issue and provide me a better code that can test internet connectivity 
Thanks 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getAllNetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworkInfo())  is deprecated

you need to use: [getActiveNetworkInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetwork())

code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            // connected to wifi
            Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            //connected to Data
            Toast.makeText(context, activeNetwork.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        // not connected to the internet
    }
```

Comment: Hello Welcome to stack overflow ...if the answer helps mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign left of the answer..

Answer (score 0):

From the [`ConnectivityManager` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworkInfo()):

> `NetworkInfo[] getAllNetworkInfo ()`
>
> **This method was deprecated in API level 23.**
>
> This method does not support multiple connected networks of the same type. Use [`getAllNetworks()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworks()) and [`getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)) instead.

Bear in mind `getAllNetworks()` was introduced in API Level 21, so you may need to run two separate approaches [based on the user's OS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically).

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    // Use getAllNetworks()
} else{
    // Use getAllNetworkInfo()
}
```