# Kivy + PyJnius check android version

Tags: android, python, kivy, pyjnius

Is there any way to get the android version (4 or 5 or 6 or 7) directly from python or pyjnius?

If so, could anyone make an example?

I tried `kivy.platform` but it only tells me if it is android or not and using `platform.release` from python gives me the linux version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pyjnius to retrieve the version via the Java API, as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

You can use my module from [here](http://pyandroid.000webhostapp.com/) (On page click download > Only file) and put downloaded file into folder with your kivy project. Add to your .py file:

```
import PyAndroid
```

Now you can use:

```
print(PyAndroid.android_version())
```

To print android version or

```
print(PyAndroid.android_name())
```

To print android name

For all functions you can read [documentation](http://pyandroid.000webhostapp.com/docs.html).

I hope I helped :D

Comment: This project web-site is now dead. The code is still available on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/PyAndroid/), but there is no documentation and no support. Spoiler: It looks in a file called "/system/build.prop" for the entries for "ro.build.version.release" and "ro.build.version.sdk". Please consider reviewing and refactoring the code before including it in a project.

Comment: @Oddthinking Yes, I know. I was working on this project back when I was 11 years old. Now it's obsolete (android permissions changed since then and now non-root user in some android versions doesn't even have rights to read file /system/build.prop). I will keep this "project" on PyPi because it may be useful for someone but for now it doesn't have any practical usage. BTW thanks for your attention ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I wanted to know the version to decide whether to reference a particular class which didn't exist in versions earlier than SDK 23.

Then I realised there was a better way.

```
try:
    AudioFocusRequest = autoclass('android.media.AudioFocusRequest')
except jnius.JavaException:
    # Not available on earlier versions of Android.
    AudioFocusRequest = None
```

Now, I don't need to know what the version actually is, and there won't be any bugs where I get the threshold values wrong. I just check whether the AutoFocusRequest exists before I use it.