# How to determine Android operating system via code

Tags: android, operating-system, notifications, android-c2dm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve the android sdk version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882883/how-to-retrieve-the-android-sdk-version)

I'm developing an Android app that needs to provide notifications. For operating systems prior to 2.2 I'm going to use polling, but for new operating systems I want to utilize the new C2DM method. Is there a way to detect which operating system the application is installed on via code? Or is there a better way to go about this altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html