# Action bar : check platform version in Java

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-ndk

I would like to check in which platform my app is running.

To be more accurate, I would like to check if my app is running on **Android v3.2 and greater** or running on a platform **older than Android v3.2** .

But I have no idea how to make this kind of checking in Java code ? Any one can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;`
It returns the API level.

Comment: Note that Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is only available on Android 1.6 and newer. Build.VERSION.SDK will work on all Android releases, including 1.5. However, once you elect to drop 1.5 support, switching to SDK_INT is a good idea. **Read this comment at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1883201/379693**

Comment: you should comare it to fx.: Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2 ... more info about Build.VERSION_CODES take from sankar answer

Comment: @PareshMayani API 1.5 ... well there were only one or two phones with this API and we should not bother about this version

Answer (score 0):

you can check by using `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES` it will return current android version code

Refer this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html