# What is android minSdkVersion for Kindle Fire running software version 6.3.2?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I'm am trying to figure out if the latest Kindle Fire OS version 6.3.2 is based on Android version 4.x.   I would like for our app to drop support for versions less than 4.0, but I would like to maintain support for Kindle Fire.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html), it's based on 2.3.3 (they make it nearly impossible to tell this from within the device.)

Comment: You are right.  I thought it might have changed when I read this... http://liliputing.com/2012/09/amazons-new-kindle-fire-tablets-run-android-4-0-if-it-matters.html

Comment: The ones that run 4.0+ are Kindle version 10+; no idea if versions 7-9 ever existed. Just to confuse you, they put out a non-HD new Kindle Fire that does run the new OS.

Answer (score 2):

The original Kindle Fire is API level 10.
The new Kindle Fire and all the Kindle Fire HD devices are API level 15.

This, and additional information about the 5 Android Tablets that Amazon has in market can be found here: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  It is API level 10 (Android 2.3.3–2.3.7 Gingerbread ).  I confirmed it by printing Build.VERSION.SDK in a log, and running my app on the Kindle Fire.

The following links are helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8982437/505093
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_2.3.3.E2.80.932.3.7_Gingerbread_.28API_level_10.29