# Android SDK: retrieve version of sdk tools from CLI?

Tags: android, command-line-interface

***note:** I'm not writing Java code, and don't need the SDK version at runtime (answers for that exist at [1882883](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882883/how-to-retrieve-the-android-sdk-version) and [3423754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)).*

I'm working on a command-line tool that needs to ensure `aapt` is on the path, and since it used to live under `package-tools` until [SDK Tools Revision 22](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) when it moved to `build-tools`, I'm looking for a way to know which folder I should add to the path for a given SDK installation.

Looking for the absence of `build-tools` seems ambiguous because it might indicate a fully functional but old SDK, or it might be that the user has a fresh download and hasn't yet run `android update sdk` yet.

Questions:

- I can't find anything like `android --version`.. is there a way to use the CLI tools to retrieve their version?
- How can I (from the command line) generate a list of which android tools are installed and what their respective versions are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse (for example using `awk`) the `source.properties` file which is located at `<android-sdk>\tools`.

The `Pkg.Revision` value indicates the version of the SDK Tools component.